# Pegar retorno de Procedure no Oracle

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oracle

Preciso executar uma procedure no banco (Oracle) que me retorna um um caractere (S ou N), estou usado o driver ODP.NET, já tentei de tudo e não consegui fazer isso, inclusive olhei varias respostas aqui mesmo no S.O PT e no S.O EN também.

Eu coloquei o codigo abaixo pra informar que é command type é uma procedure.

```
cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

Informei o parametro de output:

```
OracleParameter param = cmd.Parameters.Add("p_retorno", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
param.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
```

Tentei pegar o retorno assim:

```
string retorno = cmd.Parameters["p_retorno"].Value.ToString();
```

assim:

```
string retorno = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

e assim:

```
OracleDataReader data = cmd.ExecuteReader();
string retorno = data.GetString(0);
```

Mas a variável de retorno vem sempre vazia, a proc é executada normalmente mas não consigo pegar o retorno.

Answer (score 0):

Está faltando definir o tamanho do VARCHAR

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var connection = new OracleConnection();
        try
        {
            using (var oracleCommand = new OracleCommand("PROC_TESTE", connection)
            {
                CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            })
            {

                var pRetorno = new OracleParameter("P_RET", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Output);
                pRetorno.Size = 1;
                oracleCommand.Parameters.Add(pRetorno);

                connection.Open();

                var b = oracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Console.WriteLine(pRetorno.Value);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                connection.Close();
        }
}
```

A proc de teste:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE PROC_TESTE
(
    P_RET OUT VARCHAR2
) IS 
BEGIN 
  P_RET := '2';
END;
```